# Actions on Google: Does account linking persist/refresh while testing in Alpha?

Tags: oauth, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Alpha testers are forced to re-link their account after awhile. Is this expected behavior or is something wrong with my refresh flow? I am using OAuth authorization code linking, initialization works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes account linking should persist and I suggest checking out [this](https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments) for more information on Alpha and Beta testing with Actions on Google.